# AOSP setgid/setuid have no effect

Tags: root, android-source, su

I'm experiencing a very strange behavior from `setgid()`/`setuid()`. They don't return an error code, but don't adjust the process permissions either.

This is KitKat, SELinux is disabled (tried with permissive too).

Sample code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (setgid(0) || setuid(0))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "su: unable to setgid/setuid!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "su: getgid: %d, getuid: %d\n", getgid(), getuid());

        char *args[argc + 1];
        args[0] = "sh";
        args[argc] = NULL;

        int i;
        for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        {
            args[i] = argv[i];
        }

        execv("/system/bin/sh", args);
    }
}
```

The output is that `getgid()`/`getuid()` are still 1000, instead of 0.

Launched shell at the end also doesn't have root permissions (getting permission denied on most commands/scripts).

I've looked at su.te (this code is replacing existing su, just to make it easier to test in an existing AOSP project), and added:

```
allow su self:capability { setuid setgid };
```

Which doesn't help either.

I also tried adding `setgroups(0, NULL);` before `setgid()`, but that didn't do anything.

What else could be missing/wrong?

---

EDIT: Reading through some more information, it's possible that the /system folder has nosuid set on it, but looking through `init.rc`, it doesn't appear to have that set specifically.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this - apparently the issue was with the sticky security bit not set on the executable.

Comment: can you explain more,please?